# How to have access to a button that's outside of my current UIView? UIKIT ; Xamarin.ios native;

Tags: xamarin.ios, uikit

I am sorry for my dumb question but I have a class that is an UIView and it has a button that will change the data in my ViewController. How can I access the click button that is in that class so the data in my ViewController can change?

Thank you for your time guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an EventHandler in your UIView and invoked in ViewController when you clikc the button .

#### in your UIView

```
public event EventHandler ButtonClickEvent;

//...
button.TouchUpInside += Button_TouchUpInside;
```

```
private void Button_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   EventHandler handler = ButtonClickEvent;
   handler?.Invoke(sender, e);
}
```

#### in  ViewController

```
yourUIView.ButtonClickEvent += ButtonClickHandler;
```

```
private void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // change the data here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I tried to use an EventHandler but it wasn't working. I guess I didn't do some things right. Thank you again, that's just what i needed :)